# TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER input type on android scrolls ScrollView to it's right end. Why?

Tags: android

I have a HorizontalScrollView, in which I have an EditText. If I don't set any input type, it works just as expected. However, if I use TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER, it scrolls to the right end when I select it. Why? How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text input has a left gravity/justification and number input has a right gravity/justification.

You can override this either in your layout xml or programmatically.

```
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/etNumbers"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:hint="@string/et_number_hint"/>
```

or

```
EditText etNnumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNumbers);
etNumber.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
etNumber.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
```

Post your existing implementation and I can edit this with an actual code solution.

Comment: Thanks, that actually worked. But why? Why did gravity/justification influence scrolling?

Comment: I'd guess that your EditText goes (some amount) beyond the bounds of your current view of you horizontal ScrollView. When you activate the EditText the focus scrolls to the 'caret position'. For plain text that is the left side no your scroll doesn't need to move, however because numeric input has that right gravity the focus goes to the end of the EditText and the ScrollView need to shift its focus to include that position.