# Android Horizontal View Edit Text Input Type

Tags: android, android-edittext, scrollview

I have a horizontal scroll view and, in an item of this scroll view I have an edit text. Its gravity set as center. If I don't set any input type it works well and also if I set gravity of edit text to left and set input type to any type it works well, but when I set any input type with gravity center it scrolls to last element of horizontal view ? Can anyone help me ?
Thanks in advance.
Both of them is a part of scroll view. First one works well whereas second one is not.
For note: they are not in same xml, I did to just show you to both.

```
<EditText
                            android:id="@+id/NameOfToDo"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="192"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="20dp"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                            android:inputType="text"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:gravity="left"
                            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                            android:background="#00000000" />

     <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/NameOfToDo"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="192"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="20dp"
                            android:text="Kişisel Gelişim"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                            android:inputType="text"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                            android:background="#00000000" />
```

Comment: shoe code snippet what you have done

Comment: Could you share you xml code snnipet ?

Comment: I add it to question @YahyaMukhtar

Comment: both edittext  with same id? and post whole file with scrollview

Comment: They are not working simultaneously, the first one is works but i want it like second one.

Comment: @Tugberk yes whatever the fuction they have but how can both have same id in same xml? :O Post full file plzz

Comment: I think you could not get it, for now it is just as first one, I copy and paste it to show you to both of course they are not in same xml.

Comment: @VishvaDave is it something about scroll view ? I dont think so, also similar problem is here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23941955/type-class-number-input-type-on-android-scrolls-scrollview-to-its-right-end-wh

Comment: @Tugberk May be possible try that solution then once

Comment: @VishvaDave I tried it of course and it works as I said if I set gravity to left, but I want to set gravity to center.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the layout weights and set the width of each item in the scrollview in some other way. Layout weights in scrollviews are invalid.

Comment: No, because as mentioned here the problem is about something different, I could not solve it :(               
                             
                             
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23941955/type-class-number-input-type-on-android-scrolls-scrollview-to-its-right-end-wh